# What is the difference between shared/public/assets on production server and pre-compiled assets on rails public/assets on source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I pre-compiled my assets i.e CSS,javascript and fonts files in order to reduce the file size. Using `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`.

I already have compressed assets on the server in the following path:

**shared/public/assets**

But anyway I went ahead and pre-compiled them again on my local and they got generated inside **public/assets** folder. I noticed that the compressed files are exactly as same as the ones on server **shared/public/assets**. But the tester in my team is been testing it on some online tools. And they all say "Your java script files need to be minified." So, would this "minifying" issue be solved if I push these locally pre-compiled assets to production source code?

Comment: Rails guide is pretty good on this topic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 3):

You should not push locally pre-compiled assets to production source code, no.
Your build process should include precompiling assets for production during a deploy. If you're using Rails 5 then that is already turned on by default. As long as the production environment has a proper environment variable (again, by default, the environment variable 'production' takes care of all these things), the assets will be precompiled.


You say that your compressed files, after running rake assets:precompile, are exactly the same as the ones on the server. That means your javascript should have and should be minified and uglified (again, default for Rails 5). To confirm that's the case, open dev tools in chrome, hard-reload (ctrl+shift+r) and check with JS files are being loaded under "network" tab. If the asset pipeline was used as it should be, you should only see minified and uglified js files here. If you open them up, they should already be minified and uglified. If that's not the case then either the asset pipeline wasn't used for fetching the JS files or your build process has been changed.  
If most of these JS files are minified and uglified with - check those which aren't. Is some library being added outside of asset pipeline? Are those files minified?

If all of your JS files are actually minified, then tell your tester to use a different tool ;)

Comment: I checked by inspecting. There are no `.min.js` extension files. I see one `assets/applicatioin-ddcdcdmcmmdkd8d88dc.js` . So is that a issue?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue for the online tool reporting your JS isn't minified. Most of them detect a minified JS as a JS with a .min.js extension. That's not necessarily the case, though. Open up your JS file (in browser). Do you see any spaces? Are the variable names like you defined them in the source code, or are they different (eg. single letters 'a', 'b', 'c' etc)? If you see no spaces and the variables are mostly single letters, then your JS is minified. It doesn't matter whether it has a .min.js extension, ultimately, it might only matter for the tool your tester is using.